# OpenSearch: how do I find polygons within a given bounding box?

Tags: elasticsearch, geojson, opensearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I've attempted:

```
GET thing/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "location": {
            "top_left": {
              "lat": 47.7328,
              "lon": -122.448
            },
            "bottom_right": {
              "lat": 47.468,
              "lon": -122.0924
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...but get the following error:

```
"failed_shards" : [
  {
    "shard" : 0,
    "index" : "geofence",
    "node" : "rLGHWGhqRTqDxDlhjA3hhA",
    "reason" : {
      "type" : "query_shard_exception",
      "reason" : "failed to find geo_point field [location]",
      "index" : "geofence",
      "index_uuid" : "sBbXbANQROeQ15IzmBRf3g"
    }
  }
]
```

...as such I added:

```
PUT /thing/_mapping
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "point": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...which returns the following error:

```
"type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
"reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [mappings : {properties={point={type=geo_point}}}]"
```

This query works:

```
GET geofence/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "geometry": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "envelope",
          "coordinates": [ [ -90.0, 90.0], [ 90.0, -90.0] ]
        },
        "relation": "WITHIN"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...but this isn't a bounding box and fails for anything outside of -90.0 such as -122.0

given the following geometry:

```
      "geometry" : {
        "type" : "Polygon",
        "coordinates" : [
          [
            [
              -122.661806,
              45.596338
            ],
            [
              -122.661324,
              45.597164
            ],
            [
              -122.661865,
              45.597326
            ],
            [
              -122.662461,
              45.597532
            ],
            [
              -122.662868,
              45.597652
            ],
            [
              -122.663405,
              45.597825
            ],
            [
              -122.664381,
              45.598088
            ],
            [
              -122.66421,
              45.598846
            ],
            [
              -122.663995,
              45.599551
            ],
            [
              -122.663974,
              45.599672
            ],
            [
              -122.664135,
              45.599844
            ],
            [
              -122.663898,
              45.600662
            ],
            [
              -122.664574,
              45.60088
            ],
            [
              -122.665272,
              45.601008
            ],
            [
              -122.665808,
              45.601128
            ],
            [
              -122.666162,
              45.599799
            ],
            [
              -122.665304,
              45.599582
            ],
            [
              -122.665411,
              45.599046
            ],
            [
              -122.66599,
              45.597269
            ],
            [
              -122.66378,
              45.596884
            ],
            [
              -122.661806,
              45.596338
            ]
          ]
        ]
      },
```

What is the correct way to query for a list of polygons within a bounding box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  GET thing/_search
  {
    "size": 1000,
    "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": [
          {
            "terms":{
              ...
            }
          }, {
            "geo_shape": {
              "geometry": {
                "shape": {
                  "type": "Polygon",
                  "coordinates" : [[
                    [-180, 75],
                    [-50, 75],
                    [-50, 0],
                    [-180, 0],
                    [-180, 75]
                  ]]
                },
              "relation": "within"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

This gives an actual coordinate based lookup vs the bbox (or whatever an envelope actually is)...

The above coordinates draw a box around N. America.

Answer (score 0):

The error states

> failed to find geo_point field [location]

So you need to add a `location` field of type `geo_point` in your mapping this way:

```
PUT /thing/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_point"
      }
  }
}
```

And then your first query will work provided you make sure to index data into the new location field. Your first query, however, will just find "points" within the given bounding box.

If you want to find polygons within a bounding box, you need to use the [`geo_shape` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-shape-query.html) on a `geo_shape` field

Comment: I actually tired that as well.  I may have fat thumbed it but I found another solution to get the outcome I was looking for.

Comment: This must work, provided you have reindexed your data after changing your mapping